# ImageMagick kmeans with alpha transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to apply kmeans to an image with an alpha mask. It should only work on the colors that are visible. I'm hoping to one-line it. Starting image:

[image: SpaceshipTransparency.png]

Naively apply kmeans (whoops, all one color):

```
convert SpaceshipTransparency.png -kmeans 12x20 KmeansOnly.png
```

[image: KmeansOnly.png]

Experiment. Run through all alpha choices. `-alpha remove` seems to work somehow but it has a white background? Need to remove this and I found a three step process on ImageMagick docs by outputting a mask as a middle step:

```
convert SpaceshipTransparency.png -alpha Remove -kmeans 12x20 AlphaRemove.png
convert SpaceshipTransparency.png -alpha extract mask.png
convert AlphaRemove.png mask.png -alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite ThreeStepProcess.png
```

[image: ThreeStepProcess.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine commands by chaining using [parenthesis processing](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis) and [in-memory (MPR:) images](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#mpr) in Imagemagick.

Try:

```
convert SpaceshipTransparency.png -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -alpha Remove -kmeans 12x20 \) \
\( mpr:img -alpha extract \) \
-alpha Off -compose CopyOpacity -composite OneStepProcess.png
```

Note: -kmeans is only available on Imagemagick 7. So I recommend using magick rather than convert.